# how to use UIActivityViewController with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to access `UIActivityViewController` from MonoTouch with the following code:

```
var textToShare = new NSString("hallo there");
var activityItems = new NSObject[] {textToShare};
var excludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] { new NSString("UIActivityTypePostToWeibo"),       new NSString("UIActivityTypeMessage") };
var activityViewController = new UIActivityViewController(activityItems, null);
activityViewController.ExcludedActivityTypes = excludedActivityTypes;
this.PresentViewController(activityViewController, true, null)
```

The iOS action sheet is displayed but the specified activities are not excluded.
Any suggestions what the problem is? Are there any MonoTouch samples for this?

Answer (score 6):

You were close. Change this:

```
var excludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] { 
    new NSString("UIActivityTypePostToWeibo"),
    new NSString("UIActivityTypeMessage") 
};
```

into:

```
var excludedActivityTypes = new NSString[] {
    UIActivityType.PostToWeibo,
    UIActivityType.Message
};
```

Note: The name of the constant is not always identical to it's value. Also it's common (even if bad practice) for ObjC to compare the `NSString` pointers (not their values) to detect constant equality - creating your own `NSString` instance won't work in such cases (anyway the exposed `const` are much better looking and work better with code completion from the IDE).

Comment: This was what I needed. I knew there was something wrong with the strings pointers but I couldn't find the the correct const. Thanks.

Comment: @user1819208 Great. Please take the time to mark the question as answered so other people, looking for the same/similar, question can see an answer is available. Welcome to SO!

Comment: how we can include linkedin in ExcludedActivityTypes?